# Unit Test Class it not Public when using mockito to mock grpc server

Tags: java, mockito, grpc

I want to mock my grpc server so I can test my client but I am having an issue using junit (4.13.2) with mockito (4.1.0) to unit test my grpc client - I've been attempting to follow along using [grpc-java/HelloWorldClientTest.java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClientTest.java), but have been getting the following error:

```
[junit] Running com.ServiceManagerTest$1
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.072 sec
     [java] Timeout: killed the sub-process
     [java] Java Result: -1

BUILD FAILED
/home/user/repos/test/build.xml:256: Test com.ServiceManagerTest$1 failed
```

The raw unit test result shows this error:

```
<testcase classname="com.ServiceManagerTest$1" name="initializationError" time="0.006">
    <error message="Invalid test class &apos;com.ServiceManagerTest$1&apos;:&#xa;  1. The class com.ServiceManagerTest$1 is not public.&#xa;  2. Test class should have exactly one public constructor&#xa;  3. No runnable methods" type="org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError">org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class &apos;com.ServiceManagerTest$1&apos;:
    1. The class com.ServiceManagerTest$1 is not public.
    2. Test class should have exactly one public constructor
    3. No runnable methods
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    </error>
</testcase>
```

I learned that this issue occurs immediately once I implement the mock service and its override:

```
private final ServiceManagerServiceGrpc.ServiceManagerServiceImplBase serviceImpl =
            mock(ServiceManagerServiceGrpc.ServiceManagerServiceImplBase.class, delegatesTo(
                    new ServiceManagerServiceGrpc.ServiceManagerServiceImplBase() {

                        @Override
                        public void update(UpdateRequest request,
                                                          StreamObserver<UpdateResponse> responseObserver) {
                            responseObserver.onNext(UpdateResponse.getDefaultInstance());
                            responseObserver.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }
            ));
```

Full Unit Test Here:

```
package com.ServiceManager;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.inprocess.InProcessChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.inprocess.InProcessServerBuilder;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import io.grpc.testing.GrpcCleanupRule;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo;


@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ServiceManagerTest {

    /**
     * This rule manages automatic graceful shutdown for the registered servers
     * and channels at the end of the test
     */
    @Rule
    public final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();


    private final ServiceManagerServiceGrpc.ServiceManagerServiceImplBase serviceImpl =
            mock(ServiceManagerServiceGrpc.ServiceManagerServiceImplBase.class, delegatesTo(
                    new ServiceManagerServiceGrpc.ServiceManagerServiceImplBase() {

                        @Override
                        public void update(UpdateRequest request,
                                                          StreamObserver<UpdateResponse> responseObserver) {
                            responseObserver.onNext(UpdateResponse.getDefaultInstance());
                            responseObserver.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }
            ));

    private ServiceManager client = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        // Generate a unique in-process server name
        String serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName();

        // Create a temporary server, add the service, and register with grpc cleanup for automatic shutdown
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder
                .forName(serverName).directExecutor().addService(serviceImpl).build().start());

        // Create a client channel and register for automatic shutdown
        ManagedChannel channel =
                grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder
                        .forName(serverName).directExecutor().build());

        // Create a ServiceManager client using the in-process channel
        client = new ServiceManager(channel);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateRequest() {
        ArgumentCaptor<UpdateRequest> requestCaptor =
                ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UpdateRequest.class);

        client.update("3");
        verify(serviceImpl)
                .update(requestCaptor.capture(), ArgumentMatchers.<StreamObserver<UpdateResponse>>any());
        assertEquals("3", requestCaptor.getValue().getUpdateId());
    }
}
```

I was able to narrow it down to once I implemented that mock service the issue occurs.

I've also tried moving the declaration of the mock service implementation within the unit test itself to see if was just misbehaving when scoped at the class level - However, that resulted in the same issue.

So why does including this implementation of the grpc service cause confusion with classes?

Comment: Have you tried making the test class `public` as the error message suggests, and as the example you linked to does?

Comment: Oh yes, it is public - That was the first thing I fixed, but it still results in the exact same error despite being public.
Updating code in question.

Comment: `com.ServiceManagerTest$1` (the $1 means this is the anonymous extension of `ServiceManagerServiceImplBase`) isn't a test class, so it makes sense junit couldn't run it. But why is junit trying to run it? What are you using to run junit (Maven, Gradle, an IDE, etc)? I expect you have a wildcard in your configuration that is globbing all classes to run with junit instead of just `*Test` classes.

Comment: Yes, I am using ant with a junit task in which I have the structure using "com/**/*.class" to identify my classfiles. I also double checked that my grpc ImplBase class files are also included in the same directories. I have several non-grpc unit tests working fine.